# Locked out of drupal 7 site

Tags: drupal-7

I managed to lock myself out of my site. I have been editing template files and am afraid I am over my head. I did some research and since I removed the navigation to click the link to the user page I just typed it into the url

http://fource:8082/?q=user

This worked before but now the page no longer has the login form on it. I replaced the block.tpl file thinking that I had deleted some important code but not response. Any ideas as to what went wrong and how to recover from this.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove more of you customize template files. Because the page.tpl.php or html.tpl.php could interfere. So I would start there. You could just copy them to a other folder for testing and trying coping them back one by one.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was I was locked out so whatever changes I made couldn't be updated. I had to remove the theme all together (backed up in another location), go to phpmyadmin and empty the cache tables to reset the theme, log back in to re-enable the theme and make the changes to the page.tpl file where I accidentally erased the the content php call.